# How can I use Lisp in Autocad 2024 to extract block attributes and save them into an Excel file?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I am looking to utilise Lisp in Autocad 2024 to extract block attributes and save into Excel file to save time. Autocad 2024 supports Lisp but DATAEXTRACTION.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```lisp
(defun c:extract-objects-to-csv ()
  (setq dwg-file (getfiled "Select CAD File" "" "dwg" 1))
  (setq output-file "C:\\Users\\meme\\Desktop\\lisp\\output.csv")
  (extract-objects-to-csv dwg-file output-file)
)

(defun extract-objects-to-csv (dwg-file output-file)
  (setq obj-list '()) ; List to store object data

  (vl-load-com)
  (setq acad (vlax-get-acad-object))

  (vl-catch-all-apply
    '(lambda ()
       ; Open the drawing file
       (setq doc (vla-open acad dwg-file))
       (if doc
         (progn
           ; Get the ModelSpace
           (setq ms (vla-get-modelspace doc))

           ; Iterate through all the entities in the ModelSpace
           (setq entity (vla-item ms 0))
           (while entity
             ; Extract the desired data from the object
             (setq obj-data (list
                             (vla-get-objectname entity)
                             (vla-get-layer entity)
                             ; Add more properties as needed
                           ))

             ; Add the object data to the list
             (setq obj-list (cons obj-data obj-list))

             ; Move to the next entity
             (setq entity (vla-next entity))
           )

           ; Close the drawing file
           (vla-close doc)

           ; Write the object data to a CSV file
           (setq f (open output-file "w"))
           (foreach obj (reverse obj-list)   ; Reverse the order of objects
             (write-line 
                (apply 'strcat 
                    (mapcar 
                        '(lambda (item) 
                             (strcat "\"" item "\"")))
                    obj)
                f)
           )
           (close f)

           (princ (strcat "\nObject extraction completed. "
                "The results are saved to the specified file."))
         )
       )
     )
  )
)

; Load the command when the LISP file is loaded
(c:extract-objects-to-csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD yyyy\Express\attout.lsp extracts to a TSV, modify that. The command in AutoCAD is (duh) ATTOUT in Express Tools.